# Type information not correctly resolved by Roslyn Semantic Model

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I am not able to retrieve the type information for a field, using the Semantic Model of Roslyn. It works for field of simple types like int or string, but not for Dictionary<,>.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;

namespace SemanticsCS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
            public class MyClass {
             int z;
             Dictionary<string, string> dict;
             int Method1() { int x = 3; return 0; }
             void Method2()
             {
                int x = Method1();
             }
        }
    }");
            // 
            Dictionary<string, string> dict;
            var Mscorlib = PortableExecutableReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
            var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("MyCompilation",
                syntaxTrees: new[] { tree }, references: new[] { Mscorlib });
            var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);

            //Looking at the first method symbol
            foreach (var nodeSyntax in tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes())
                {
                var methodSymbol = model.GetSymbolInfo(nodeSyntax);
                var symbolInfo = model.GetSymbolInfo(nodeSyntax);
                var typeInfo = model.GetTypeInfo(nodeSyntax);

                if (typeInfo.Type != null)
                    Console.WriteLine(nodeSyntax.GetText() + ":" + typeInfo.Type.Kind);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when I run it, I get

```
             int :NamedType
             Dictionary<string, string> :ErrorType
string:NamedType
string:NamedType
                         int :NamedType
int :NamedType
3:NamedType
0:NamedType
                         void :NamedType
                                int :NamedType
Method1():NamedType
```

I suppose ErrorType is a default used by Roslyn when the actual type is not retrieved.

The definition for Dictionary should come from mscorlib. Can it be that it is not found? Or, do I need to change something in the code? Apparently it is working on one of my colleagues computers, but not on mine. Is is a matter of configuring the usage of .Net?

Comment: You need to use the full type name `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>` or ausing statement

Comment: @Kalten is probably correct. You can also get the errors/warnings using [`compilation.GetDiagnostics()`](http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Compilation/Compilation.cs,8caaa5f6fc695b41) which should make it easier to figure out exactly what's going wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I missed the fact that the VB code used for testing did not include the Imports statements, so even if I had the reference to mscorlib, the namespace was not known. It worked after I added the namespace prefix.

Answer (score 2):

Defining a reference assembly is not enought to tell to the compiler where a class name come from. You must specify either the full type name (`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>`) or define via using statement.

To help you understand errors you could take a look to diagnostic report. (From CSharpCompilation or SyntaxTree).

```
foreach (var d in compilation.GetDiagnostics())
{
    Console.WriteLine(CSharpDiagnosticFormatter.Instance.Format(d));
}
```

It will give you this :

```
(11,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
(4,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Dictionary<,>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point
(5,30): warning CS0219: The variable 'x' is assigned but its value is never used
(4,37): warning CS0169: The field 'MyClass.dict' is never used
(3,14): warning CS0169: The field 'MyClass.z' is never used
```

The following error is the namespace error.

> (4,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Dictionary<,>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

But you can see that some other are there. The following is here because of the extra `}` at the end of the script.

> (11,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

End the last one :

> error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Is because, by default the compiler try to build an executable instead of library. You can change that with `OutputKind` enum.

```
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
    "MyCompilation",
    syntaxTrees: new[] { tree },
    references: new[] { Mscorlib },
    options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary));
```

Edit :

If you want to find the OutputKind from an existing csproj file, you can do it like that : (inspired by [this gist](https://gist.github.com/DustinCampbell/32cd69d04ea1c08a16ae5c4cd21dd3a3)

```
// Nuget :
// https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build.Locator
// https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild/
// https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis

if (!MSBuildLocator.IsRegistered)
{
    MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults();
}
using(var wp = MSBuildWorkspace.Create()){
    var project = await wp.OpenProjectAsync(@"pathtocsprojfile.csproj");
    Console.WriteLine(project.CompilationOptions.OutputKind);
}
```

Comment: I understand, it makes sense. Question: If I had a whole C# solution, is this information (executable vs. library) coming from the project definition? How do I get it? Use MSBuild?

Comment: I added this info at the bottom of the answer